# Numerical value returns differ from actual

Tags: delphi, rad-studio, turbo-pascal

This might be a commonly known thing, but I wonder if there is any best practice of dealing with **data spill-over** in Delphi.

Say I have a variable `Dt` that is assigned a value of `0.01` in code. When Delphi runs through it, the value of `Dt` in debug mode is `0.0099999997765`, slightly off the actual value of `0.01`. Although the values are not significantly different, using `Dt` in an iteration of `10000` steps will lead to it.

Any suggestion on how to force `Dt` to `0.01`? Also, I am using Delphi 2003, so there are constrains on what I can do.

```
Dt:= 0.01    //Debug value = 0.0099999997765
.
for I=0 to 10000
   temp := temp + Dt;
```

The issue is more prominent as `temp` starts to spill, as well resulting in an answer that far off what is expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is how floating-point numbers work. It is impossible to "force" `Dt` to be exactly 0.01. But you are clearly using single-precision variables. You get much better approximations if you instead use double-precision variables.

Comment: Or don't use floating points at all if you only need a fixed position - i.e. when only down to 0.0001 is needed then just use `Integer` or `Int64` and operate on that, and only when outputting it divide it by 10000.

Comment: A [document](https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf) usually referred to.

Comment: What is the actual data type of `Dt`?  If it is a `TDateTime` then don't use floating-point values directly at all. `TDateTime` uses a `Double` internally, but is not treated as a normal floating-point number. Use the `TDateTime`-related functions in the `SysUtils` and `DateUtils` units to manipulate `TDateTime` values without losing precision.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'd guess `Dt` is a time difference, like `Δt`.

Comment: Some brilliant minds commented on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667061/822072

Comment: 0.01 cannot be represented as a binary floating point number.  Here is its nearest representation as an Extended, Double, and Single value: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.01